# Get the full QueryString from URL in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url, query-string

I have an URL with the following format:

```
http://www.mysite.com/login.aspx?ref=~/Module/MyPage.aspx?par=1&par2=hello&par3=7
```

I use the content of the `QueryString` it to `Redirect` the user back to the page he was before logging in. In order to keep also the status of the page I need the parameters in the `QueryString`. The number of parameters changes depending on the `Page` calling the `Login` and its status.

Let's say I want to store everything in the URL after `ref` in the `redirectURL` variable. I tried:

```
 redirectURL = Request.QueryString("ref") // "~/Module/MyPage.aspx?par=1"
```

it gets everything after `ref` but ignores everything after the `&`(included). If I use:

```
 redirectURL =Request.Url.Query // "ref=~/Module/MyPage.aspx?par=1&par2=hello&par3=7"
```

it gets everything, `ref` included. In order to achieve my goal I need just to remove the first 4 characters from the redirectURL. But I think this solution is a bit "forced" and I am sure there should be some ASP.NET function that accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&`s in your URL are creating additional querystring arguments.

You need to escape the value of the `ref` parameter before putting it in the querystring.
This will replace the `&`s with `%26`.
To do this, call `Uri.EscapeDataString()`.

When you fetch the property from `Request.QueryString`, it will automatically decode it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider Encoding "`~/Module/MyPage.aspx?par=1&par2=hello&par3=7`" before passing it to the url.

Eg.:

```
String MyURL = "http://www.mysite.com/login.aspx?ref=" + 
                Server.UrlEncode("~/Module/MyPage.aspx?par=1&par2=hello&par3=7");
```

And then, you can get the redirectURL using:

```
String redirectURL = Request.QueryString("ref");
```